# JQuery Isotope - gaps disappear when filtering with a responsive grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm working with Isotope to create a responsive gallery on http://samsnow.alwaysdata.net/galerie. I looked up on stackoverflow how other people did that and I made my own piece of code but I need some help here please.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

var $container = jQuery('#containerGalerie');
var columns = 4,
setColumns = function() { 
        screen = jQuery(window).width();
        if(screen>1630){
            columns = 5;
        }
        else if(screen>1280){
            columns = 4;
        }
        else if(screen>710){
            columns = 3;
        } 
        else if(screen>345){
            columns = 2;
        }
        else{
            columns = 1;
        };
        largeur=100/columns - 0.5;
        jQuery('.element').css('width', getLargeur);
        function getLargeur(){
            return largeur +'%';
        }
    };
setColumns();

jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){
    setColumns();
    $container.isotope({
         itemSelector : '.element',
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
          // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
          masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / columns}
    });     
}).smartresize();

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    jQuery(window).smartresize();     
});


var $optionSets = jQuery('.option-set'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){  
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    /*
    if ( $this.parent().hasClass('active') ) {
        return false;
    }*/

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.parent().addClass('active');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
    key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
    value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
        // changes in layout modes need extra logic
        changeLayoutMode( $this, options );
    } else {
        // otherwise, apply new options
        $container.isotope( options );
    }
    jQuery(".isotope-item a").attr("rel", "visible");
    jQuery(".isotope-hidden a").attr("rel", "nonvisible"); 
    jQuery(window).smartresize(); 
    return false;
});
```

});

Since I use % width for my images and a variable number of columns I've a bug on the filter. After a click on a filter the most of the gaps between images disappear. This is fixed with another click on the filter, or even a sligth window resizing.

I don't understand what's happening. Does someone could help me please?

edit : Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SamSnow/8Am8N/1/

Comment: have you tried to "relayout" or "reload", after applying filter?

Comment: Thanks articlestack but it did'nt work (I tried to put $container.isotope('reLayout') in smartresize() and at the end of .click()).

Comment: Can you make a reference example on JSFiddle? I hope to solve your problem.

Comment: Sure my post is edited. If you don't understand everything I said  in english contact me for details.

Comment: I visited JSFiddle link in chrome and found everything fine even after filter. Should I share screenshot?

Comment: Try again with a different width for the frame. Do not forget that it's only the width from the scrollbar so it's not a big space but it's enough to get one above the others depending on the browser width. You can for example click on the last filter because in this category you'll not have a scrollbar (and click again on this category to see the bug fixed). If you don't find the bug share me a screenshot ;)

Comment: Hi, did you give up? :(

Comment: sorry dear. I have tried FF & Chrome. and can't see bug anywhere. I have tries by restoring browser in 3 different widths. Still it is working fine. No idea why you are facing the issue.

Comment: Damned that's strange. Here you can see what is going on : http://i.imgur.com/yOlB598.jpg It seems to me that the bug is related to the scrollbar but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: really strange. what browser and os you are using?

Comment: Windows 7, firefox & chrome. It's maybe about the screen resolution, mine is 1920*1080 and you?

Comment: Mine is 1380x768. Unfortunately, I can't increase it. You try on low resolution and see whether it is behaving fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem is : it's the transition from a filter with a lot of images (my page has a scrollbar) to another one with few images(=no scrollbar). When the scrollbar appear/disappear there is no refresh! 
Unfortunately I have'nt managed to fix it.

I rely on your help!